# In the below code I am not getting the desired result as -2-2i. Getting result as -2+-2i

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below code I am not getting the desired result:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math

import os

import random

import re

import sys


class comp:

    def __init__(self,real,img):
        self.real=real
        self.img=img
        
    def add(self,p2):
        r= p1.real+p2.real
        i= p1.img+p2.img
        print("Sum of the two Complex numbers :"+str(r)+'+'+str(i)+'i')
        
    def sub(self,p2):
        r= p1.real-p2.real
        i= p1.img-p2.img
        print("Subtraction of the two Complex numbers :"+str(r)+'+'+str(i)+'i')  
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    real1 = int(input().strip())
    img1 = int(input().strip())
    
    real2 = int(input().strip())
    img2 = int(input().strip())
    
    p1 = comp(real1,img1)
    p2 = comp(real2,img2)

    p1.add(p2)
    p1.sub(p2)
```

The code works but when the imaginary field takes a result in -2, it is printing the result as +-2i

**Result**
eg: 1+2i - 3+4i = **-2-2i**
(but as it is hard coded as "+" in the comment it is resulting in **"-2+-2i"**

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: No idea what your problem is. Maybe add some inputs and what you want to get out vs what the program does?  Seems to be a controlflow issue if you calculate something that is incorrect fix your calculations.....

Comment: @PatrickArtner I would want to get the answer printed as -2-2i  in the console. But it is printing as -2+-2i           Also, the code is working fine for other test cases. So I couldn't  understand what can be done.

Comment: Please take a moment to understand how code-formatting works in Markdown - the code in this post has been repaired twice by community members now.

Comment: Consider looking at your code carefully and using conditionals

Comment: Are you aware that complex numbers are a built-in datatype in Python?  `i1 = 1+2j` / `i2 = 3+4j` / `print(i1-i2)` works right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional printing - either with an `if` clause or by leveraging an inlined [ternary expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator):

```
r = 5
for i in (-2,0,2):
    print(f"Subtraction : {r}{'+' if i >= 0 else ''}{i}i")
```

Output:

```
Subtraction : 5-2i
Subtraction : 5+0i
Subtraction : 5+2i
```

You may want to make a print function though, to handle 0*i and 1*i more gracefully